# Iterating Xpath to get the elements in Dom4j Parser

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

I am new to Dom4j Parser and i am trying to solve the problem through Xpath Construction ,

This is my sample Xml

```
<List>
  <names>
       <name>
       <FirstName>Raju</name>
       <age>20</age> 
       </name>
       <name>
       <FirstName>Kamal</name>
       <age>30</age> 
       </name>
  </names>
</List>
```

When age is 30, i need to remove that particular name block from my Xml
**Ex:**

```
   <name>
   <FirstName>Kamal</name>
   <age>30</age> 
   </name>
```

So the logic i use is ,I am constructing Xpath for names and then iterating each names

```
XPath names=DocumentHelper.createXPath("/List/names");
List<Nodes> nameslist=names.selectNodes(document);
for(Node name:nameslist)
{
/*
code block for retrieving the name element
*/
}
```

But i am not able to construct a path for age and check it ,Please suggest me how to construct a Xpath for age.

Comment: You mean something like `/List/names/name[age="30"]`?

Comment: @Andersson its like /List/names/name[2]/age="30" or /List/names/name[2]/[age="30"]